# useWatch dose not trigger re-rendering in Jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I'm writing tests for the following React component which handle image files with `react-hook-form`.

```
type Props = {
  name: string;
};

const ImageUploader = ({ name }: Props) => {
  const { control, setValue, register } = useFormContext();
  const imageUrl = useWatch({ control, name });

  const handleInputChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const files = e.currentTarget.files;
    setValue(name, files && files.length ? URL.createObjectURL(files[0]) : '');
  };

  const handleInputClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.value = '';
  };

  const handleDeleteButtonClick = () => {
    setValue(name, '');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label data-testid="upload-button">
        UPLOAD
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onClick={handleInputClick}
          {...register(name, { onChange: handleInputChange })}
        />
      </label>
      {imageUrl && (
        <button onClick={handleDeleteButtonClick} data-testid="delete-button">
          DELETE
        </button>
      )}
      {imageUrl && <img src={imageUrl} data-testid="uploaded-image" />}
    </>
  );
};
```

The test code is below.

```
type FormValue = {
  image: string;
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  const methods = useForm<FormValue>();

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <ImageUploader name="image" />
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

describe('ImageUploadArea tests', () => {
  test('test', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<TestComponent />);
    const imageFile = new File(['imageimageimage'], 'imageFile.png', { type: 'image/png' });

    const inputElement = screen.getByLabelText('UPLOAD') as HTMLInputElement;
    user.upload(inputElement, imageFile);

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByTestId('uploaded-image')).toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```

`ImageUploader` works properly on browsers but in Jest tests, the delete button and image seem not to appear.
And it seems to be because the re-rendering is not triggered after `user.upload(inputElement, imageFile)` even though there is `useWatch()` in `ImageUploader`. (I checked that re-rendering was not triggered by `console.log()`.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because Jest doesn't have implementation of `URL.createObjectUrl` method.
So `imageUrl` in `ImageUploader` component had always falsy value then delete button and image didn't show up.

I solved this by adding mock implementation.

```
jest.spyOn(URL, 'createObjectURL').mockImplementation(() => 'CREATED_OBJECT_URL!!!');
```